# bash не срабатывает сравнение строк

Tags: bash

```
batStat=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)
[ "$batStat" != "Discharging" ] && (let limit=limit-1; batStat="+") || batStat=""
```

После выполнения фрагмента *batStat* остаётся содержащим "Full" (текущий статус из файла). То есть не выполняется ни истинное, ни ложное срабатывание. Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в данном случае вместо вызова *subshell*-а:

```
(let limit=limit-1; batStat="+")
```

логичнее использовать простой блок кода:

```
{ let limit=limit-1; batStat="+"; }
```

ведь у него нет кода возврата (в отличие от *subshell*-а).

---

а вообще (на начальных порах освоения нового языка программирования) лучше, мне кажется, не «экономить на спичках» и писать развёрнуто:

```
batStat=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)
if [ "$batStat" != "Discharging" ]; then
 let limit=limit-1; batStat="+"
else
 batStat=""
fi
```

код сразу становится понятнее, и, главное, работает так, как и ожидается.

Comment: Ну, с bash я не настолько на вы, чтобы прямо "начальная пора". С блоком вот только напутал.